# Please check these code

Tags: if-statement, equals

could you check these codes?
I can't find the problem.
"If" has no action!
It should check username and password and age.
After that if all of details are true will answer true unless will answer false.But "If" don't answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Class2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int age;
        String password = "big.110@go";
        String username = "big";

        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your Usename: ");
        username = keyboardInput.next();
        System.out.print("Please enter your age: ");
        age = keyboardInput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
        password = keyboardInput.next();
    if(keyboardInput.next().equals(username)
            && keyboardInput.nextInt() >= 18
            && keyboardInput.equals(password)) {
                System.out.print("Welcome");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Something is wrong!\n Try again");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the point of `keyboardInput.next().equals(username)`? Prompt for a username earlier, then check if some other input equals what was entered earlier?

Comment: I didn't understand what you said!

Comment: could you explain clear?

Comment: every time you call keyboardInput.next(), it gets input from the user. you prompt for username/age/password, then get input AGAIN when you do `keyboardInput.next().equals(username)`,

Comment: I think now i find what is wrong! Thank you

Comment: no. it won't.`String username='big'; username=keyboardInput.next()`. you're overwriting the values you set earlier.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: brush up on your programming skills. your code is full of logical problems, and that's not something we should just give you the answers for. Run through the code on paper and learn what each statement is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You made a lot of mistake in your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Class2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

      int age;
      String password1 = "big.110@go";
      String username1 = "big";

      Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter your Usename: ");
      String username = keyboardInput.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
      String password = keyboardInput.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Please enter your age: ");
      age = keyboardInput.nextInt();

      if(username.equals(username1)
              && password.equals(password1)
              && age>=18 ) {
          System.out.print("Welcome");
      } else {
          System.out.print("Something is wrong!\n Try again");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer with explanations.